# How to describe this kind of jewelry?

Tags: image-identification

"In one of the photos he took then, there is a young woman who has (...?) on her face".

I found myself in a problem when I want to name this specific jewelry (that falls on the cheeks) in order to maximize the description in words. Maybe in English people would use borrowed words (such as Indian) to describe it?

[image]

In the Chinese site that I found it (it's translated by machine probably) it's described as: "Chran New Sexy Women Multi Layer Tassel Head Chain Headdress Jewelry Forehead Headband Eye Cover Face Mask Body Jewelry".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is not a common form of jewelry, at least in the UK/US, it does not have any standard name.  Different people will describe it in different ways, and it's likely you'd have to show someone a picture to get them understand what you mean.

For example, on [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/market/face_mask_jewelry), this sort of jewelry is sold under many different names: *face mask, face veil, face chain, chain mask*, and others, and often include descriptions that suggest who might use it, such as *masquerade, gothic, festive, bohemian,* and so on.

The title on the site you mention is not intended to be a *description* of the jewelry, but rather a list of *keywords* used by people searching for this sort of item.